# Breeze - not return changes introduced in BeforeSaveEntities to client?

Tags: breeze

I am struggling to find a solution to a conceptual problem re BeforeSaveEntities.

In short, I want to avoid the server informing the client about entity deletions which I introduce in the savemap in BeforeSaveEntities.

The longer story follows below :-)

**Data structure:** I have an entity called PrimaryData, which has some parallel loosely coupled entities called SecondaryData. For each PrimaryData, there exists a number of SecondaryData's.

**Business Logic:** Whenever the user deletes a PrimaryData on the client, the server should delete any related SecondaryData.

**Security requirement:** The client should not be informed that the SecondaryData's have been deleted.

**Implementation:** I have implemented a BeforeSaveEntities function, where I catch the deletion of the PrimaryData, and add additional EntityInfo's for the SecondaryData's that I also want to delete to the SaveMap.

Things work as expected. Both the PrimaryData and the SecondaryData's get deleted.

**Problem:** Unfortunately, the XHR shows that the return package to the client includes the SecondaryData's which have been deleted. This violates my Security Requirement above, that the client should not be told about the deletion of the SecondaryData. The client does not need to know about the SecondaryData in this part of the application, so there is no functional need for the information to be transferred. I am going to reload the cache anyway.

**Question:** Is it possible to instruct breeze not to return the deleted SecondaryData's? E.g. by a setting in the EntityInfo that I can add to the SaveMap?

br
Morten

Comment: 3 words: code, snippet, please

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way for Breeze to do this.  You can just remove the offending entities from the SaveResult before you send it back to the client.  I don't know what server-side technology you are using, but here's how it might look in .NET WebAPI:

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    SaveResult sr = _context.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    // remove entities of type SecondaryData
    sr.Entities = sr.Entities.Where(e => e.GetType() != typeof(SecondaryData)).ToList();
    return sr;
}
```

Comment: I was kind of expecting that this was not a built-in functionality :-/ Your suggestion to remove the SecondayData's from the SaveResult is good. It will work for the use case in this question.

Comment: But I have another use case where the user manipulates the SecondaryData's directly on the client. Obviously this will not work with the above SaveChanges. I guess I could then create a named save for the use case in this posting, which will remove SecondaryData from the SaveResult. But a determined user could circumvent this by using the normal SaveChanges, which will return the deleted SecondaryData. Since the overall purpose is to hide my business logic from a determined user, I am kind of stuck.

Comment: My question was answered by Steve with a suggestion that will work for the use case I stated. I will credit your for this. But I think my solution will be to make the deletions directly in the database using Entity Framework from the BeforeSaveEntities function. I will need to be careful about the context that I will be using, but should be possible. This will circumvent Breeze, and thus breeze will not be able to tell the client about it.

Comment: Besides the named save, you could decide what to do on the server (removed or keep SecondaryData) based on other information.  For example, the user's identity, or the other entities in the change set.